# SEO friendly urls containing / in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, seo, slug

I am currently working on transferring pages from a wordpress to a new Rails application to save time on reindexing i would like to keep same url structure

These urls contain /

There for having a page with slug /p/chapter/part/section gives me /p/chapter%2Fpart%2Fsection in the url after rendering

I know module [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#M009387) is available but i simply dont know how to implement it

what i have dont to achieve Slug style url is

Pages controller

```
def set_page
  @page = Page.find_by_slug(params[:id])
end
```

and Pages model

```
def to_param
 "#{slug}"
end
```

routes

```
resources :pages , :path => 'p'
```

if anyone could help it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you use `URI.unescape("/p/chapter%2Fpart%2Fsection")` you will get `"/p/chapter/part/section"` Does that help advance with your problem?

Comment: not really if i run that in a console thats fine the issue is how do i make my routes use it

Comment: Your slug needs to be this whole part `chapter/part/section`, or you need to have more routes and maybe models to accomodate for chapters, parts and sections... 

Having something similar to a route of `get '/p/:chpater/:part/:section' => 'pages#show'`

Comment: my slug does contain it all inside to elustrate @page.slug will give me "chapter/part/section" and when i visit the page my url on local at the moment shows /p/chapter%2Fpart%2Fsection  i need to allow the forward slashes appear in url rather than the encoded characters

Comment: Use the `URI.unescape("#{slug}")` on your `to_params` method

Comment: i did it made no change the slug still works but still contains the %2F